# Send the same SMS to multiple numbers using AT commands

Tags: at-command

I need to send a message to multiple recipients using AT commands.

I'm using this through excel vba.

```
Public Sub SendSMS()
  Dim MSComm1          As New MSComm
  Dim strSMSRecipients As String

  strSMSRecipients = "xxxxxxxxxxxx; yyyyyyyyyyyy"

  With MSComm1
      .CommPort = 1
      .PortOpen = True
      .Output = "AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf
      .Output = "AT+CMGS=""" & strSMSRecipient & """" & vbCrLf
      .Output = "Hi, World!" & Chr(26)
  End With
End Sub
```

It works fine if it's sent to only 1 recipient.

Is there any command for sending to multi recipients or do I have to loop and sending one by one?

Thank u in advance.

Comment: I think this is not a Excel-VBA question because it is related to how the command for multiple SMS should look like which has nothing to do with VBA at first. It is not Excel or VBA that sends the SMS it is a 3rd party tool you are using (or what ever hides behind your MSComm). So I doubt that any of the VBA gurus here can answer that question. This is more a question about AT commands or something else. • Nevertheless what I can say from VBA side: Looping would work if you already managed sending single recipient SMS.

Comment: Tanks.. Edited.

Comment: I've been trying to do this before, but could never find a way, other then looping each message... I made an array with all the numbers and looped until `UBound(Array)`

Comment: Thank u so much.. Me too couldn't find any other solution so far.

Comment: Did u use CMMS in ur code or just CMGS?

Comment: Didn't use CMMS, only CMGF and CMGS

Comment: when I loop and send using CMGS it only sends to the 1st number. I think I need a delay between each number.

Comment: Can't remember having that issue.. I have the code on a old computer at home. I can take a look after work in about 6 hrs :)

Comment: I appreciate that. Thank u so much

Comment: Did u take a look yesterday?

Comment: Need your help here plz